# unable to use cscope multi key stroke via vim editor

Tags: linux, vim, rhel, cscope

I am using **VIM 7.0** on **RHEL release 5.4**, and downloaded cscope plugin from: *http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim*

and copied it to path(one instance at a time): `~/.vim/plugin/cscope_maps.vim` & `/usr/share/vim/vim70/autoload`

and generated `cscope -qbR` from root dir of source files, & opening `*.C` files from same dir.

According to [this(point 5)](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html) & **cscope_maps.vim**, I should be able to do keyword search by multiple keystroke: `CTRL-\ <option>` or `CTRL-@ <option>` by placing the cursor under the keyword as we do for ctags. But I am able to access the cscope keyword search only through the vim's command line argument (ie., `:cs f d` or `:cs f c`) and not with multiple key stroke shortcut.

I've also tried pasting all the contents of **cscope_maps.vim** to `~/.vimrc`, but it didn't help

Is there something I am doing wrong/ any other way to make it work?

Comment: As you can see in `cscope_maps.vim` it didn't talk about `VIM7` so please check syntax of that script in `VIM7`. like here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html

Comment: Vim 7.0 is from 2006 and _very_ outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 7.4; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution, it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the Mercurial sources) on Linux.

Comment: @MortezaIpo yes nothing mentioned about `VIM7`, but i assumed for all `VIM6+` the `cscope_maps.vim` file to be placed in VIM's plugin folder?

Comment: @Ingo Karkat do I need to recompile latest `VIM` and `cscope` or only `VIM` would do? Right now I am using both `VIM` and `cscope` as included in `RHEL5` package

Comment: @DragonX if you check http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=51 , in the `vim version` it supports `vim 6`

Comment: My comment was just a general note on that you're missing out on many enhancements and bug fixed with Vim 7.0; your problem is probably unrelated.

Comment: @MortezaIpo yes, but I am using `VIM7`. As mentioned in link above,  cscope's native GUI works fine, but not the point 4.  Isn't it true that the higher versions of VIM has inbuilt support by default?

Comment: @DragonX yes , maybe it support.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the plugin's documentation, copy the plugin to

```
~/.vim/plugin/cscope_maps.vim
```

The `autoload` directory you've chosen is wrong, this is for plugins' on-demand functionality.

Also, `/usr/share/vim/vim70/` is owned by the default Vim package, don't touch anything there (in general), or you'll run into problems when reinstalling / upgrading packages! If you do need to have a system-wide plugin, check `:help runtimepath` and find / add a proper location that *you* own on the system.

Comment: the path `~/.vim/plugin` didn't exist so I created one and pasted the `cscope_maps.vim` file in it, and removed the same from `autoload` path, but still no luck

Comment: Does it appear in `:scriptnames`? Does `:echo has("cscope")` yield `1`? Do the mappings appear in `:nmap <C-\>`?

Comment: yes, it does appear as `7: /root/.vim/plugin/cscope_maps.vim` when i do `:scriptnames` & also doing `:echo has("cscope")` yields `1`. And for `:nmap <C-\>` i got `No mapping found` in VIM's cmd prompt

Comment: Strange, so the plugin is sourced, but the mappings aren't defined. You could run this with `:set verbose=20`, or try changing the mappings inside the plugin, or adding `:echomsg "here"` debug information.

Comment: cscope is mapping `<C-]>` only to check the function definition and not `<C-\>`. The plugin has key binding `<C-\>` definitions, right? or some modification in plugin required?

Comment: Right, `<C-]>` is built-in.

Comment: yes, but using `<C-]>` in cscope doesn't jump from definition to calling function, this doesn't make sense as this can be also done via `ctags`

Answer (score 1):

Probably your code base is other then .c files. I was facing same issue as my code base includes c and c++ both. I was trying with c++ functions and was facing same issue you mentioned.
Hint- Build cscope data base with all required files.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are missing the `CSCOPE_DB` environment variable - i.e, it should point to the valid `cscope.out` file

To check, once you are in `vim`, run `:echo $CSCOPE_DB`, mine shows:
`/home/me/views/myrepo/cscope.out`

Comment: i checked, `env` is not set. so I export `CSCOPE_DB` myself to the particular `~/src/cscope.out` file, even then its not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with cscope and Vim 7.4. I could solve it in Arch uncommenting in cscope_maps.vim the bellow lines:

```
set timeoutlen=4000
set ttimeout
```

BTW I followed this tutorial to install cscope vim plugin on Arch:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/vim#cscope